# Python and win32 API - using a C file

Tags: c++, python, winapi

With ActiveState Python comes a win32api module. I need to implement something that monitors directories recursively for file-changes. Actually there's [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the MSDN library using C. I don't know whether the win32api bindings are sufficient for something like this.

Can I import this into a Python project? Because it may be easier to write the file-alteration monitor itself in C, and to handle the results within Python. The problem is: how do I make that interact with each other.

Comment: It would be significantly easier to write the directory watcher in Python. It's basically three or four lines: `os.walk`, checking what you see against some stored list of what you was last time.

Comment: @katrielalex I think he wants something kernel-level like `inotify`

Comment: @katrielalex: @user59300: Yes, but using windows native event system is better. It is similar to pyinotify that is used on Linux. See the link below.

Comment: @user59300: Tim Golden's example is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not try some of the python win32 examples here. It uses pywin32 and does what you want.

- http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

The "C" code that you have mentioned with link to MSDN uses *FindFirstChangeNotification*. Tim Golden's example uses the same through python win32 bindings. I guess this is what you want.

All windows APIs are exposed and can be utilized via pywin32.

Comment: Note that what that page says about `ReadDirectoryChangesW` blocking so you can't exit the loop, is not a limitation of the Win32 API.  Not sure whether you can do overlapped I/O in python though.

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind regarding Twisted - sounds very interesting ;)

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation and try it out for yourself.  [win32file](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32file.html).[FindFirstChangeNotification](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32file__FindFirstChangeNotification_meth.html), etc. are there and work.